# Making a game in LibGDX with collision and gravity without using Box2D

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx, game-engine

I want to make a game in LibGDX and I would like to put in it some gravity and of course collision between objects. Can I do it without Box2D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Try having a Vector2 gravity for the world, and one Vector2 velocity for each object. Then every frame modify the velocity using the gravity. And then the position using the velocity (so it starts to fall for example).

```
Vector2 gravity = new Vector2(0, -1);

myobject.velocity.add(gravity);
myobject.position.add(myobject.velocity.x*delta, myobject.velocity.y*delta);
```

And the collisions can be made using Rectangles and their overlaps method:
[Rectangle#overlaps](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html#overlaps%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle%29)